# Handle out of sync point issue via IBM JMS from Mule

Tags: jms, mule, ibm-mq, xa, mule-esb

I am connecting MQ-8.x from Mule via JMS and recently I had faced an issue that seems like MQ write operation is going out of sync point range and due to this and also the huge inbound load, MQ went in to deadlock state.

```
<spring:bean id="ConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" name="ConnectionFactory">
        <spring:property name="hostName" value="xxxx" />
        <spring:property name="port" value="xxxx"/>
        <spring:property name="queueManager" value="xxxx"/>
        <spring:property name="transportType" value="1"/>
        <spring:property name="channel" value="xxxx"/>
   </spring:bean>

<jms:connector name="JmsConsumer" username="xxxx" password="xxxx" specification="1.1" connectionFactory-ref="ConnectionFactory"  numberOfConsumers="1" validateConnections="true"  persistentDelivery="true" doc:name="JMS"/> 

<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="xxxx" connector-ref="JmsConsumer" doc:name="Audits"/>
```

My operation volume will be move but its just a PUT operation, so I am really not sure whether XA or other Transaction manager to be needed in this.

Comment: Sounds like your jms:connector isn't committing the transactions ? Maybe you should try  transactionalAction="ALWAYS_JOIN" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been handled in MQ-9.x version that MQ itself will manage the out of sync point implicitly.  MQ-9.x upgrade will be the solution for this kind of issue.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026865_.html

Comment: You should accept your own answer, note this change was added in MQ 9.0.5 CDS release and is present in the new MQ v9.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

This message is produced because persistent messages are being produced out side of a transaction. MQ is highly optimized to process transactional persistent messages and this warning is informing us that the queue isn't being processed as efficiently as possible. The system will receive a significant performance improvement if you make the actions inside a transaction/syncpoint or if non persistent is good enough turn the persistent flag off.